# How to pull highest value out of an array and double its value

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, combinations

So I have some code which gives me combinations. I'd like to find the highest *driver_points* value from each combination and then double its value.

Here's my code currently:

```
     # DRIVER AND TEAM ARRAYS
     driver_points = { "john" => 18.1, "mike" => 19.3, "paul" => 15.6, "mark" => 1.1 }
     driver_price = { "john" => 4.0, "mike" => 5.0, "paul" => 6.0, "mark" => 2.1 }
     team_points = { "cowboys" => 20.1, "bears" => 19.3, "lions" => 15.6, "united" => 2.8 }
     team_price = { "cowboys" => 1.0, "bears" => 2.0, "lions" => 3.0, "united" => 2.4 }

    # DEFINE VARIABLE AND TARGET
     teams = team_price.keys
     drivers = driver_price.keys
     target = 13.5

    # CREATE METHOD TO SUM BOTH PRICES AND POINTS FOR GIVEN COMBINATION
    def add_up(combo, ht, hd)
      t, d = combo
      ht[t] + hd.values_at(*d).sum
    end

    # ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS OF TEAM AND DRIVERS
    all_driver_combos = drivers.combination(3).to_a
    all_combos = teams.product(all_driver_combos)

    # SHOW ALL COMBOS WHERE SUM DOES NOT EXCEED TARGET
    valid_combos = all_combos.select do |c|
      add_up(c, team_price, driver_price) <= target
    end

    # SORT VALID COMBOS BY SUM OF POINTS FOR EACH ELEMENT
    ordered = valid_combos.sort_by do |c|
      -add_up(c, team_points, driver_points)
    end

    #OUTPUT
    @combo = ordered.map do |c|
      { c.join(" ")=>{ price: add_up(c, team_price, driver_price),
             points: add_up(c, team_points, driver_points).round(2) } }
    end
```

Which is currently outputting combinations (1 team and 3 drivers) based on the target value but sorted by highest points:

`[{"cowboys john mike mark"=>{:price=>12.1, :points=>58.6}}, {"bears john mike mark"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>57.8}}, {"cowboys john paul mark"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>54.9}}, {"united john mike mark"=>{:price=>13.5, :points=>41.3}}]`

I'd like to be able to find the highest driver, based on highest *driver_points* from each combo, and double its points value.

For example in my first outputted combination: `{"cowboys john mike mark"=>{:price=>12.1, :points=>58.6}}`

I want to be able to find the highest scoring driver of the three - this would be one of john, mike and mark as I don't want to include the team. Answer is Mike since he has 19.3 points. And then double Mike's driver points, which should then update the *:points=>* sum. Giving a new total points of 77.9. Also, I'd like to be able to move the highest points driver to the start of the driver combo for styling purposes in the view.

So my desired output is this:

| Team | Double | Combo | Price | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cowboys | mike | john mark | 12.1 | 77.9 |

Comment: There seems to be some discrepancy between your question's rather simple title and your complex looking code / problem description. Apparently you want more than just fetching some highest value from an array. You mention drivers, teams, points, and prices but you don't really explain what these values mean or how the data is relevant to the problem you are trying to solve. There's also an HTML table involved. Maybe you could simplify your code / question / problem so it becomes easier to understand. Remove irrelevant data, code, and details. Explain what's remaining.

Comment: You should always begin your question with a statement of what you are trying to do. Add one or more examples if you think it will help readers understand your question. When giving examples always show the desired return values, which must of course be valid Ruby objects. Once you have done that you can present your code. If you have given examples show the results you get with your code, which of course will be incorrect. You have started your question by presenting your code. It's obviously difficult for readers to understand your code if they don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks both, I think I confused the situation by trying to ask multiple questions at once in an attempt to be able to solve my question myself. I have just asked the question directly, and that should improve my understanding immensely anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have computed

```
valid_combos
  #=> [["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears",   ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["united",  ["john", "mike", "mark"]]]
```

Consider the combo

```
c = ["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]
        20.1      18.1    19.3     1.1
```

where the team points for `"cowboys"` and the driver points for each of the three drivers in this combination are shown above. (Someone needs to have a word with Mark.)

The total points for this combination is seen to be

```
add_up(c, team_points, driver_points)
  #=> 58.6
```

To this we wish to add `19.3` points, which are driver points for `"Mike"` as he has the most points among the combination's three drivers:

```
58.6 + 19.3
  #=> 77.9
```

We can do this in code as follows.

```
def add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points)
  t, ds = combo
  dmax = ds.max_by { |d| driver_points[d] }
  driver_points[dmax] + add_up(combo, team_points, driver_points)
end
```

For the combination `c` defined above,

```
add_dbl(c, team_points, driver_points)
  #=> 77.9
```

as expected. We may now use `add_dbl` in place of `add_up` to sort the combinations.

```
ordered = valid_combos.sort_by do |c|
  -add_dbl(c, team_points, driver_points)
end
  #=> [["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]]
```

---

The following code rearranges the drivers so that the driver with the highest driver points appears first in each array of drivers in `ordered`.

```
ordered.each do |_t,ds|
  imax = ds.each_index.max_by { |i| driver_points[ds[i]] }  
  ds.unshift(ds.delete_at(imax))
end
  #=> [["cowboys", ["mike", "john", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["mike", "john", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["mike", "john", "mark"]]]
```

See [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index), [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by), [Array#unshift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift) and [Array#delete_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at). Note that [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns its receiver (`ordered`) but we are modifying that array.

---

To merely sort the drivers, from highest to lowest driver points, modify the above expression as follows.

```
ordered.each do |_t,ds|
  ds.sort_by! { |d| -driver_points[d] }
end
  #=> [["cowboys", ["mike", "john", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["mike", "john", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["mike", "john", "mark"]]]
```

Coincidently, these arrays of drivers are no different than the ones above.

See [Array#sort_by!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21).

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with this! Just to confirm, is the final output in this (showing all combinations), an array? I am attempting to place all these combinations in a table but seem to be having problems. I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345706/convert-a-list-of-combination-arrays-to-a-html-table

Comment: Yes, combinations are given in an array. Regarding your other question, I regret I cannot help because I don't know Rails. I'm retired and Ruby is just a hobby. Perhaps another reader could help or you could post another question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - just one quick question: In your `def add_dbl` section, is it possible to add a condition that the doubling method only applies to a driver that has a price less than or equal to a set price. I would define a new variable: `double_target_price = 20`. But where would I place my new  `<= double_target_price`? I am assuming it would go between the   `dmax =` line and the  `driver_points[dmax]` line. So it would double the highest driver points, but only if the value is less then target price - do you think this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the requirement correctly you could write `add_up(combo, team_points, driver_points) +  driver_price[dmax] <= set_price ? driver_points[dmax] : 0`.

Comment: So inside my Method to double highest points I now have this:
`def add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points)`
 `t, ds = combo`
`dmax = ds.max_by { |d| driver_points[d] }`
 `add_up(combo, team_points, driver_points) +  driver_price[dmax] <= set_price ? driver_points[dmax] : 0`
`end` 

Your code is definately attempting to do what I would like,  but it is throwing an error: undefined local variable or method `driver_price' for #<HomeController:0x00000000068ba0>

Comment: Sorry, you need to add the argument `driver_price` to the definition of `add_dbl`: `def add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points, driver_price)`.

Comment: Hmm I did try that but then get the following error: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 4)

Comment: It looks like you executed it with the same three arguments as before: (`add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points)` ("given three"). You need to execute it as `add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points, driver_price)` ("expected four").